# Volatility in parallel stream api

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-stream, volatile

See one of the JDK stream api collectors below:

```
    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Integer>
    summingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper) {
        return new CollectorImpl<>(
                () -> new int[1],
                (a, t) -> { a[0] += mapper.applyAsInt(t); },
                (a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; return a; },
                a -> a[0], CH_NOID);
    }
```

Considering using parallel processing, it is clear there is no need in any synchronization and it is safe to use a non-concurrent containers `() -> new int[1]`, since each such container is created and filled with accumulator `(a, t) -> { a[0] += mapper.applyAsInt(t); }` in a separate thread. Then all these containers are combined in a separate thread with combiner `(a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; return a; }` into a final result.

Meanwhile, JLS postulates that the reader thread may not see the actual value of non-volatile field if this field was somehow updated in another thread (because of thread caching and other JMM features). But considering the example collector, you can see that a plain int array is used, the elements of which are not volatile. I can't figure out why a plain int array is used here, instead of e.g. AtomicIntegerArray, when the non-volatile element `int[0]` is updated in one thread and then is read in other thread that performs combining.

**Could you please explain why it is safe to use containers with non-volatile mechanics in stream api using parallel processing?**

Comment: Because the parallel reduction takes care of the memory visibility with the necessary memory barriers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is that every parallel thread receives it's own individual copies of the container (one element int array), which they update independently of each other. No volatile required for the array access.

Once the threads run out of source values, they use a memory barrier that ensures their individual array entry is properly published, then "dance" with each other to perform the combining of these individual containers. Each such combination is then followed with yet another memory barrier. This goes on until only one container remains.

The actual implementation is a bit more involved. Check out [ReferencePipeline.collect](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#L672).

Comment: The first part is pretty clear, no volatile needed if value is only updated in same thread. But the second part is not that clear. How is this achieved that finishing thread that performs combining of this individual arrays sees their actual values? How does "memory barrier" work? Am I right that "memory barrier" is a some kind of stream api implementation feature and this feature somehow uses volatile reads to ensure "happens-before" semantics? So there will be guarantee that finishing thread will see actual value of each array

Comment: Something like a volatile write on a field, i.e., `done = true`.

Comment: I strongly suggest removing the word “memory barrier” from the answer, as there is no such thing in the specification. It is enough to say that there is an implementation specific way to ensure a *happens-before* relationship between the finishing of the two worker threads and the call to the merge function with the two results or between two subsequent calls of the merge function.